# How to create a VM instance from an instance template within Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I need to start a Google Compute instance based off a template I've made which has a startup script which downloads the latest game-server executable from my server and runs it. This all works perfectly fine.

Now, my custom built matchmaker will determine if all current games (which are instances of the game server) are full, and if so I want it to run a Cloud Function that creates another new instance from the template I've mentioned above (which basically acts lobby/game for 12 players). Once the instance is created I need the cloud function to return the IP of the newly created instance back to whatever called it (which would be my game).

I know the first part is possible via `HTTP POST` but I cannot find anywhere in the cloud functions docs/compute docs/admin SDK docs that allows me to create instances and get the IP, is this possible?

EDIT: I have found this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/index.html) but I have not yet found a function to start a VM from a template which then returns the VM's object - which includes it's IP...

Comment: To start, can you tell us more about the template you are using?

Comment: @MrTech Template? It's just a custom instance that runs ubuntu with a startup script that downloads my game server executable and runs it. It has no relevance to this question, I'm asking if it's possible to run a instances based of said template through a cloud function?

Comment: How do you create your VM today? Do you use the console? the CLI?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere well at the moment I have to manually start instances from the template within the console , but I can do it either way. I want cloud functions to do it instead to tie it in with my matchmaker and make it all dynamic.

Comment: What are you talking about here `I know the first part is possible via HTTP POST`. In addition can you tell me what is your development language?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I can create an instance based off a template via a `HTTP POST` as stated here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template#api I just need to know how to do the same in cloud functions. And Node.JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly the APIs. First create the VM, then wait the running state to get the internal and external IP

```
async function main() {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();

    const url = `https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/europe-west1-b/instances`
    const template= 'projects/PROJECT_ID/global/instanceTemplates/instance-template-1';

    const instanceName = 'example-instance'
    const body= '{ "name": "' + instanceName + '" }'

    let res = await client.request({ url: url + "?sourceInstanceTemplate=" + template,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: body
    });
    res = await client.request({ url: url + "/" + instanceName,
        method: 'GET'});

    while (res.data['status'] != 'RUNNING') {
        setTimeout(function(){},1000)
        res = await client.request({ url: url + "/" + instanceName,
            method: 'GET'});
    }
    //Internal Ip (interface0)
    console.log(res.data.networkInterfaces[0].networkIP);
    //External Ip
    console.log(res.data.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP);

}
main().catch(console.error);
```

*My NodeJs skill is low (style, format, idioms,...), but this works.*

Comment: Thank you, that would've been my last option. I assume I cannot use the `@google-cloud/compute` npm module to do such thing instead of making direct requests then?

Comment: InstanceTemplate seems not supported by [the library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest)